# Is there still tubing going on in Vang Vieng, Laos?

Tags: laos, outdoor-activities, vientiane

I've been [reading about the shutdown of tubing](http://www.vientianetimes.org.la/sub-new/Previous_198s/FreeContent/FreeConten_Committee.htm) in Vang Vieng. I'm wondering if someone has information about whether the authorities enforce the shutdown? I was there some years ago when it wasn't as bad as it got in the last few years and I hoped people would stop coming to this beautiful place just for mushrooms and cheap booze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CNNGo has a piece on this as well, explaining about how it was done](http://www.cnngo.com/explorations/life/24-signs-partys-over-vang-vieng-965782).  It sounds like there was a major expose and resulting crackdown.

[Wikitravel's page on Vang Vieng](http://wikitravel.org/en/Vang_Vieng) also states that there's been a massive shutdown.

However, the [Sydney Morning Herald reports these attempts have had 'mixed success'](http://www.smh.com.au/travel/tubing-tourists-defy-new-safety-measures-20120915-25ywb.html):

> But two days ago, the river was still busy with more than 100 tubers.
>   One bar was still serving drinks and organising volleyball matches but
>   had stopped playing music. Others operated from Eskis on the sandy
>   banks of the river, mostly for takeaway beer only.

(note, an Esky is a coolbox - Aussie word).
(note, a coolbox is a cooler - no idea who says coolbox). (-;

It seems that despite safety restrictions, you still get situations like the following occuring:

> New regulations, which are not posted anywhere in town, read “You must
>   wear a life jacket.” However, none on the river, apart from some
>   kayaking Koreans, were doing so and a staff member at the tube rental
>   asked customers, “Can you swim? Then no need."

So long answer short - yes, there was a crackdown, but no, it hasn't stopped completely - so to answer your question, you can probably still do it, for now.

Comment: I even know what an Eski is :D Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @hippietrail - ta for editing, but I did mean coolbox - it's a British word (http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/coolbox)

Comment: @MarkMayo Yeah I looked it up afterwards. Why not just call it a chillybin though? (-;